# Errors when installing chocolatey. What should I do?

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

When I load up my cmd.exe from the Windows start, I am defaulted to the command prompt, c:\Users\gameoflife directory.  I am the only person and administrator of this computer.   When I tried installing chocolatey, I get this error (screenshot included below).
Can someone please help me figure out what I might be missing. Thanks so much!
[image]

Comment: Have you started the cmd as administrator?

Comment: Yes that worked!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the instructions on the installation page:

https://chocolatey.org/install#installing-chocolatey

The initial installation of Chocolatey, either via the Command Prompt, or PowerShell, requires an `administrative shell`.  Details of how you can do this can be found here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/

It is possible to do a non-administrative installation of Chocolatey, and if this is something that you are looking to do, I would suggest that you read through this section of the documentation:

https://chocolatey.org/install#non-administrative-install

However, bear in mind this statement:

> This option should be a last resort and is considered to be a more advanced scenario - most things you do on Windows require administrative rights, especially surrounding software management, so you are going to be limited even in packages you attempt to install.